# WHMCS/TCAdmin Curl Integration Error

Tags: php, curl, whmcs

Having an issue trying to link WHMCS and TCAdmin together on my two separate servers. The error in WHMCS when trying to auto create an account is:

*Curl error: Failed to connect to x.x.x.x port 8880: Connection timed out Url: http://x.x.x.x:8880/billingapi.aspx*

From what I can see, all is setup the way it should (within WHMCS/TCAdmin). Firewall is allowing inbound and outbound connections on x.x.x.x on port 8880. I've checked, IP is correct, all appears to be setup fine... and my host at my website where WHMCS is has said that the IP and port x.x.x.x:8880 have been added as an exception to the firewall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be API related check your TCADMIN API information and also be sure to check to make sure that the API IP is whitelisted in your WHMCS security settings.